# Appium iOS: Sign out from app before each test

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, serenity-bdd

I have a `.feature` file which has many scenarios. I want user is not logged in before starting the `.feature` file. But when I test it always shows user already signed in, from the previous `.feature` test.

**I tried:**

```
appium.automationName = XCUITest
appium.platformName=IOS
appium.platformVersion = 13.3
appium.deviceName  = iPhone 11 Pro Max
appium.app=/Users/plautner/Desktop/workspace/iosApp/testDemo.app
noReset=false
fullReset=true
```

How can I make it fresh install for every `.feature` file?

I am using Mac Catalina, Appium, Java, Serenity BDD, Maven, JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using driver.quit() after running your feature file to close the session?